# How to watch .MOV files without QuickTime?

Tags: windows-vista, video, quicktime

How can I watch .MOV files without QuickTime?

I've found a solution to use the "3ivx codec", but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [videolan](http://www.videolan.org/). It's [features list](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) lists MOV as an input format.

Comment: +1 for VLC, it just keeps getting better and better...

Comment: It took a major step for the worse with the 0.9 release, though :/

Comment: Why do you say that?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try [QuickTime Alternative](http://www.codecguide.com/download_qt.htm)?

Comment: It works but it's weird to have to open a browser to be able to watch a .MOV when the .MOV is on the hard drive. And, for a weird reason in FireFox the video doesn't start if the option of Automaticly Start is not enable :S. Still +1 for the solution thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't have to open the browser to watch the MOV. It is possible that the MOV is just associated with IE. Try right-clicking and choosing Open With... and choose Windows Media Player.

Comment: This link is now dead :(

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is worth a try.

Apple has made it difficult for third parties to do anything interesting with .MOV files. Their published documentation is extremely stale, new codecs are virtually undocumented, and they have a license agreement that basicly says you won't even try.

Comment: I provided this potential-solution 2 minutes ago. Could you please up-vote my suggestion if you agree with it rather than adding a duplicate suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: I upvoted you since you were the first Jonthan.

Answer (score 1):

I use a codec pack named "K-Lite", it sometimes comes bundled with media player classic, which i don't like, so i recommend you to download the basic version, which doesn't have that player included and still supports .MOV files. [KLite-Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)

It has worked for me when trying to play those files on Windows Media Player or XBMC.